# Controling swf from another swf in different client computers

Tags: connection, flash

I'm not sure it's possible, I've been reading some examples of Flash LocalConnection feature but in the end it's only possible if the 2 swf files are loaded on the same client computer. 
The idea is to control a remote swf by pressing buttons on a local swf. Let's say I have a computer with a swf loaded on a browser and from across the web I press a button on another swf also loaded on a browser, an that pressing of the button makes an action on the first swf.

Thanks 
Miguel Barata

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need a peer-to-peer server like [Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) to establish a connection.